# When using next router events it seems to not work All the time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a loading screen in Nextjs.
whenever the user navigates to a new page ,
It shows the loading message and everything but sometimes but it just stays there and doesn't fade away,
I think this is because the state doesn't change or Router doesn't check the path after loading idk,

I tried passing a dependency array with the router, router.asPath and router.events But it stays the same.
How can I get to disappear after the page loads?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Loading() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const hanldeChangeStart = (url) => {
      url !== router.asPath && setLoading(true)
    }
    const hanldeChangeComplete = (url) => {
      url === router.asPath && setLoading(false)
    }
  
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', hanldeChangeStart)
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', hanldeChangeComplete)
    router.events.on('routeChangeError', hanldeChangeComplete)
    
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', hanldeChangeStart)
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', hanldeChangeComplete)
      router.events.off('routeChangeError', hanldeChangeComplete)
    }
  })

  if(loading){
    return (
        <div className='vh-100 vw-100 text-center'>
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
        <p>{loading ? 'loading' : 'notloading'}</p>
        </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

My app.js looks like this

```
import Loading from '@/components/Loading';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  
  return (
    <>
      <Loading />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it the problem was that I had to make a condition in `App.js`
So it only shows the loading screen when it's loading and then replaces it with a loaded page later.

```
import Loading from '@/components/Loading';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  
  return (
    <>
      {loading ? <Loading /> :
      <Component {...pageProps} />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: How do you get access to "loading" inside the App.js?